# Existence Proof Using Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-explanation, induction

From the section on induction in Miklos Bona's combinatorics book: Prove [using induction] there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n!<(\frac{n}{2.5})^n$ for all $n>N$. For what it's worth, I took this to be $$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}[n>N\implies n!<(\frac{n}{2.5})^n]$$ in quantifiers. I may be wrong on that and maybe that's why I had an issue with the problem (it's been a while since truth tables and all the rest of it).

It's one of the first - if not the first - 'existence by induction' proofs I've ever seen so begrudgingly I gave up and used his solutions manual (linked).

[image]

My proof closely aligned with his besides that I couldn't see how yellow implies blue, so I said: $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}<\frac{2.5}{2.6}<1$ when $n>m$ implies $b_{n+1}<b_n$ when $n>m$; i.e., $b_n$ is decreasing when $n>m$. Since $b_n$ is decreasing and each $b_n>0$, the sequence converges to some $\ell$. Hence $$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2.5b_nc_n=\ell\cdot\frac{2.5}{e},$$ which implies $0=\ell\cdot\frac{2.5}{e}-\ell=\ell(\frac{2.5}{e}-1).$ It follows that $\ell=0.$ So, since $b_n\to0$, there must be some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $n>N$ we have $b_n<1$; i.e., $n!<(\frac{n}{2.5})^n.$ QED.

My questions: 1. Isn't it true that both his solution and mine complete the proof, just using basic properties of sequences? Why - or where - is induction even needed? And if he somehow *was* using induction, where's his base case? 2. How exactly does yellow imply blue? 3. Any further reading on more problems like this (existence using induction)?

Comment: 1/ Yes both solutions complete the proof. 1b/ The induction is at the very last line, namely you A/ Find a $b_N < 1$, and then induct from there to show that B/ For $n > N$, $b_n < b_{n-1} < \ldots < b_N < 1$.   $\quad$ 2/ That's almost immediately. Think about it again. $\quad$ 3/ It's pretty typical induction (at least to me). The slight difficulty is finding a large enough $N$ for this to work. EG Try to prove that $ n ^{n+1}  > (n+1) ^ n$ by induction, for all $ n \geq N $(To be found, though we "know" beforehand that $N=3$.

Comment: The way I am reading the Question & the Proof , it is not really Existence using Induction. We first show Existence of some $n$ value & $N$ value using Calculus or what-ever , then we use Induction to show that all larger $n$ values will work too. The Initial $n$ value is the Base Case & the larger $n$ values are the Induction Cases. We do not use Induction on $N$ value here.